# filtering an array for a duplicate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I have an array of objects, shown below.  The first segment of code is within a loop where multiple objects of 'Item' are created and pushed onto the array.

Example of the problem is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/X6VML/
Notice how changing the value inside a textbox displays a duplicate item.

```
 // class
 var Item = function(label, value) {
    this.Label = label;
    this.Value = value;
 };

 var obj = new Item("My Label", "My Value");

 // adds object onto array
 itemArray.push(obj);
```

The problem I have is that the array can contain duplicate objects which I need to filter out before rending the list of objects into a table, shown below:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
      $('.MyTable').append("<tr><td>" + itemArray[i].Label + "</td><td>" + itemArray[i].Value + "</td></tr>");
  }
```

I can identify whether it's a duplicate with the Value being the same.  How can I filter the list of objects based on whether the Value already exists in the array?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
var temp = [];
$.each(itemArray, function(index, obj){
    var found = false;
    $.each(temp, function(tempI, tempObj){
        if(tempObj.Value == obj.Value){
            found = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(!found){
        temp.push(obj);
    }
});

itemArray = temp;
console.log(itemArray);
```

The above is simply iterating over each object in the array, and pushing it to the temp array if it's not already there, finally it overwrites `itemArray` with `temp`.

---

Have you considered eliminating duplicates at the point of adding to the array? Something like this:

```
function UniqueItemList(){
    var items = [];

    this.push = function(item){
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            if(items[i].Value == item.Value){
                return;
            }
        }
        items.push(item);
    };

    this.getList = function(){
        return items;
    }
}

var myList = new UniqueItemList();

myList.push(new Item('label1', 'value1'));
myList.push(new Item('label2', 'value2'));
myList.push(new Item('label1', 'value1'));
myList.push(new Item('label1', 'value1'));

console.log(myList.getList());
```

If you try to push a duplicate item, it will be rejected.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qPSpp/1/)** - here it is integrated into your code.

Comment: that would be ideal..  just looking at your suggestion

Comment: @JamesRadford see my edit - added a demo of it integrated into your code. http://jsfiddle.net/qPSpp/1/

Comment: thanks but when I change a value it duplicates a echoed value?  I need to update the original rather than a duplicated item.  Hope thats clear..?

Comment: please see here, it's almost complete although with my modifications although I'm not sure whether to call .clear?  http://temp-share.com/show/gFHKQRlzY

Comment: when I call 'clear' the list only shows 1 item..  -- because Clear() removes them obviously..

Comment: If it does what you want without clear then you can delete/ignore clear. Are you sure that code does what you want? I tested it and it allows duplicates, and if you type in the input, leave focus, then update it again it duplicates...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32836/discussion-between-james-radford-and-mrcode)

Comment: yes, thats the problem.  it allows duplicates now but when I add the Clear method, now called ClearList I only ever get one item in the list because obviously when using the ClearList it removes everything
not sure what makes the difference

Answer (score 1):

Just don't add duplicate item in array:

```
var item = new Item("My Label", "My Value1");

if(!$.grep(itemArray, function(obj) { return obj.Value == item.Value; }).length)
  itemArray.push(item);
```

If there is already an object with Value `"My Value1"` in `itemArray`, just don't add it.

Comment: this would be ideal obviously..  Im sure this code is great but can you rewrite it perhaps so I can see what it's doing please?  Thanks,

Comment: Check doc for $.grep() method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/. Sorry i don't understand what you mean by 'so I can see what it's doing'??? BTW, if you provide relevant code as how you add new items in array it would be more usefull.

Answer (score 0):

This code would do. Modify the itemArray before forming the HTML.

```
var arr = {};
for ( var i=0; i < itemArray.length; i++ )
    arr[itemArray[i].Value] = itemArray[i];
itemArray = new Array();
for ( key in arr )
    itemArray.push(arr[key]);
```

Comment: think its very close actually.  Can you explain what it's doing please?

Comment: because the obj.value should be unique, a map is created with obj.value as key and obj as value. this eliminates the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this handy utility function:

```
function uniq(ary, key) {
    var seen = {};
    return ary.filter(function(elem) {
        var k = (key || String)(elem);
        return seen[k] === 1 ? 0 : (seen[k] = 1);
    })
}
```

where `key` is a function that fetches the comparison key from an element.

Applied to your use case:

```
uniqueItems = uniq(itemArray, function(item) { return item.Value })
```